# In need of some advice about recreating a part of a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was looking at awwwards and saw a design i liked and thought I would try to re-create it. I've run into a bit of an issue that I would like some advice on.

[Example Website](http://hoovermason.com/#/signs/4)

That timeline part of the website is my focus. I have everything else working or planned out, but i am not sure on how to create a responsive timeline like on this site. I dont have experience with WebGL or SVG so if those are the solutions, I have a good reason to gain some experience apparently. Havent ran into a need to use 2D or 3D graphics but this may be the time.

I first tried to recreate this with rotated li text, originally using all px. Then when I realized it would have to scale, I switched over to %, but the font size is giving me issues so I dont know if this is the best course of action anymore. [My attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/9beckp6u/) (which ill also post at the end of this post, i know i didnt finish my transformations for all browsers, was testing with chrome and was going to update them when i was finished) which only works correctly when the display window is 1379px (i also didnt finish the full timeline as I thought there had to be a better way of achieving this). So I am just looking for ideas on how to better re-create this, the source code for the page wasnt helpful (at least to what I could see).

I also considered using div bottom/top borders but I wasnt sure if that was a better solution.

JSFiddle code :

```
                <body>
                    <ul> 
                <li>
                    <a href="#">________</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">________</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">________</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">________</a>
                </li>
                <li alt="5">
                    <a href="#">________</a>
                </li>
                        <li>
                    <a href="#">________</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">________</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">____</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">________</a>
                </li>
                <li alt="10">
                    <a href="#">____</a>
                </li>
                        <li>
                    <a href="#">________</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">______________</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">______</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">_________</a>
                </li>
                <li alt="15">
                <a href="#">______</a>
                </li>
                    </ul></body>
```

CSS :

```
            ul {
                margin-top: 80px;
            }
            li {
                width: 30px;
            }
            ul li {
                font-size: 50%;
                display: inline-block;
                text-transform: uppercase;

            }
            li a{
                color: grey;
            }
            li:nth-child(1){
                margin-top: -1%;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-65deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(-65deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(-65deg);
                transform: rotate(-65deg);
            }
            li:nth-child(2) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -1.1%;
                left: 5.4%;
            }
            li:nth-child(3) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -1.1%;
                left: 7.9%;
            }
            li:nth-child(4) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -1.1%;
                left: 10.5%;
            }
            li:nth-child(5) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -.8%;
                left: 13.1%;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(65deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(65deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(65deg);
                transform: rotate(15deg);
            }
            li:nth-child(6) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -.17%;
                left: 15.5%;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(65deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(65deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(65deg);
                transform: rotate(15deg);
            }
            li:nth-child(7) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: .2%;
                left: 17.8%;
            }
            li:nth-child(8) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -.4%;
                left: 20%;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(65deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(65deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(65deg);
                transform: rotate(-35deg);
            }
            li:nth-child(9) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -.6%;
                left: 21.4%;
            }
            li:nth-child(10) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -1.2%;
                left: 23.6%;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(65deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(65deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(65deg);
                transform: rotate(-35deg);
            }
            li:nth-child(11) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -1.35%;
                left: 25%;
            }
            li:nth-child(12) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -1.35%;
                left: 27.56%;
            }
            li:nth-child(13) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -.75%;
                left: 28.57%;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(65deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(65deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(65deg);
                transform: rotate(35deg);
            }
            li:nth-child(14) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -.26%;
                left: 30.19%;
            }
            li:nth-child(15) {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: -.8%;
                left: 32.71%;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(65deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(65deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(65deg);
                transform: rotate(-35deg);
            }
```

Comment: the website you exampled runs extremely slowly on my browser and took 24 seconds just to load, it seems to be really un-optimised.

Comment: @Martin yeah, its a slow loading website since a lot of their stuff is in video form or so it seems. Nothing I can do about it, but I like how it looks.

Comment: The "map" on that example site does appear to be SVG. You might find [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) or [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) useful.

Comment: @showdev alright thanks